# Searching a text string inside a LOB field using QueryDSL

Tags: java, sql, querydsl

I'm currently using QueryDSL and I must add a `WHERE` clause to filter by a field which stores a huge amount of information (readable text) and it's created as a LOB field.

This is the field in my entity:

```
@Lob
@Column(name = "MY_FIELD", nullable = true)
private byte[] myField;
```

which is generated in this way in my "Q" class:

```
public final ArrayPath<byte[], Byte> myField = createArray("myField", byte[].class);
```

I can recover the information in this field without a problem. However, when I was trying to add the filtering clause, I realized the `ArrayPath` object doesn't have a `like` method, so I tried to do it in a different way.

I tried different approaches and I came up to this:

```
Expressions.predicate(Ops.LIKE, Expressions.stringPath("MY_FIELD"), Expressions.constant(stringValue));
```

The SQL code generated with the previous predicate is the following:

```
...
WHERE
    MY_FIELD like '%?%' escape '!'
...
```

If I try to execute this SQL command directly in my database it perfectly works, it recovers the correct rows depending on the "?" param. However, my application doesn't recover any of them even though it's executing the very same SQL command.

Is there anything I'm missing? Could it be done in a different way?

Thank you very much in advance.

PS: I'm using SQL Server 2011.

Answer (score 1):

By default a `byte[]` is mapped to an Array path. In case of a (C)LOB, you want to map it as String path instead. You can hint the code generator by specifying the `QueryType`:

```java
@Lob
@QueryType(PropertyType.STRING)
@Column(name = "MY_FIELD", nullable = true)
private byte[] myField;
```

However, `@Column(name = "MY_FIELD", nullable = true)` seems to imply that you're querying JPA instead of plain SQL. Be aware that some JPA vendors may not support the `like` function for CLOBs.

Comment: If I map the field in this way then I get the following error: Parameter value [abc] did not match expected type [[B (n/a)]

Comment: I am not sure if (presumably) Hibernate can handle `like` for `byte[]` fields. To verify that you can write a JPQL query without querydsl and see if that actually executes. Otherwise I'd suggest to map the field to a `String` or `Clob`.

Comment: In that case what I get is a "Wrong column type" error from Hibernate. What I finally did was creating a view with a CLOB casted field ````(CONVERT(VARCHAR(max), MY_FIELD, 0))```` and using it instead of the original LOB one.

Not the best, I know, but I didn't find any other way to do it.

Thank you very much for your help.